# Can Reinhardt's Shield be damaged twice by the same instance of damage?

Tags: overwatch

If you fire symmetra's photon orb through a Winston bubble, it will only damage the bubble on the way in (not on the way out), does the same rule apply to a Reinhardt barrier? Also does putting away then taking the barrier back out affect this? (i.e. if the same ball collides with the barrier twice, will it deal damage to the barrier twice?)

Comment: Pretty sure it's the same as Winston http://overwatch.wikia.com/wiki/Barrier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, barriers can only be damaged once by any single instance of damage.

Comment: Does putting away the barrier then taking it back out allow it to be damaged a second time?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: AFAIK same is true for heroes.